# Using PKCE flow without client credentials for regular web applications

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, oauth

Some OAuth 2.0 providers, including Spotify and GitLab, support both the regular OAuth 2.0 authorization code grant type with client credentials (confidential client) and the authorization code grant type using PKCE without client credentials (public client). They also do not allow you to restrict it to a single method.

In such cases, where the provider accepts both methods, is there a reason to use client credentials over just PKCE?

A big advantage of confidential client is that you can't impersonate it just with their client ID, but in this case the provider doesn't require a client credential if you pass a `code_challenge` to the authorization endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 main ways to implement the code flow in an OAuth secured web app, and there is more to the end-to-end solution than just the field level details you mention.

**FRONTEND ONLY FLOW**

These implement their flow solely in JavaScript and use PKCE without a client secret. It is a relatively simple solution.

The deeper behavior, later on, is that you are likely to end up storing a refresh token in local storage, in order to get multi tab browsing working reliably. This is not recommended in real world apps.

**BACKEND FOR FRONTEND FLOW**

These follow [OAuth 2.1 recommendations](https://connect2id.com/learn/oauth-2-1) and use both PKCE and a client credential. In this case, PKCE still provides some extra protection when the browser calls the BFF, eg if a malicious authorization response is injected into the browser. Similarly, the client secret prevents malicious browser code from calling the token endpoint.

The deeper behavior is that a BFF tends to keep tokens out of the browser completely, and use an HTTP only cookie layer instead. Doing so limits the impact of cross site scripting exploits. It requires a more complex flow however.

Comment: Yes, I understand all of that, but here I'm asking if there is a reason to use client credentials when the provider accepts both the regular method and PKCE. I'm interested whether I lose most of the benefits that come with using client credentials in such cases

Comment: Use both if you can - any standards based solution will support that. If you run into non standard vendor specific behavior and have to choose one of them, prefer the client secret.